# Interpreting marginal trends of logistic model

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio

I've got a logistic model where the annual change for each subject is of interest. Regression, easy. Generate estimated marginal trend for each subject, easy. Now, I have a set of what I presume to be trends expressed as log-OR. How do I translate those into something easier to understand, like "percent change per year", for example?